# Listbox selectedIndexChanged doesn't fire when selecting an item from the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, selectedindexchanged

I have a listbox that needs to be populated by directories. 
i have successfully filled the listbox with the Directories but my problem is i can't get the selected item's value. i placed a breakpoint on the SelectedIndexChanged event but my web application doesn't seem to run through that code.

Here is my code for populating the listbox:

```
        lstDirectories.DataSource = dtDirectories;
        lstDirectories.DataValueField = "DirectoryID";
        lstDirectories.DataTextField = "DirectoryName";
        lstDirectories.DataBind();
```

This is how i get value from the listbox on the SelectedIndexChanged Event:

```
        TextBox1.Text = lstDirectories.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

am i doing something wrong here? thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Have you set the property `Autopostback = true`?

Comment: nope. it is set to false @mnieto

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the property:-

`AutoPostBack="True"`

By default it is `False`.